# Deploy Spring Boot App to Azure App Service via Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-web-app-service

I have a Spring Boot project that I would like to deploy using Azure Pipelines on an Azure App Service. The processes (build and deployment) run without problems, but I cannot access the app using the configured URL. Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong or forgotten to do?

This is the pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  azureSubscription: 'Microsoft Partner Network(de924e6e-8496-454b-b4d6-441f1a4cf975)'
  webAppName: 'batteriefinder'
  environmentName: 'batteriefinder'
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: GradlePackageAndPublishArtifacts
    displayName: Gradle Package and Publish Artifacts
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Gradle@2
      displayName: 'Gradle package'
      inputs:
        tasks: assemble
        jdkVersionOption: 1.11

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to artifact staging directory'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        Contents: '**/build/libs/*.?(war|jar)'
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    
    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: drop
  
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployLinuxWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Linux Web App
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: batteriefinder'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/**/libs/*.?(war|jar)'
```

Here are the build logs:

```
2020-07-17T10:10:16.3727487Z ##[section]Starting: Gradle Package and Publish Artifacts
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5666186Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5667545Z Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5667880Z Agent machine name: 'fv-az716'
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5668096Z Current agent version: '2.172.1'
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5715287Z ##[group]Operating System
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5715507Z Ubuntu
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5715639Z 18.04.4
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5715787Z LTS
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5715925Z ##[endgroup]
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5716086Z ##[group]Virtual Environment
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5716276Z Environment: ubuntu-18.04
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5716467Z Version: 20200709.0
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5716763Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu18/20200709.0/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5717047Z ##[endgroup]
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5718110Z Current image version: '20200709.0'
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5723321Z Agent running as: 'vsts'
2020-07-17T10:10:16.5774920Z Prepare build directory.
2020-07-17T10:10:16.6129412Z Set build variables.
2020-07-17T10:10:16.6165067Z Download all required tasks.
2020-07-17T10:10:16.6296517Z Downloading task: Gradle (2.163.2)
2020-07-17T10:10:18.4978548Z Downloading task: CopyFiles (2.164.2)
2020-07-17T10:10:18.5739503Z Downloading task: PublishPipelineArtifact (0.140.1)
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6177795Z Checking job knob settings.
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6186283Z    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /opt/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6187260Z    Knob: AgentPerflog = /home/vsts/perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6187829Z Finished checking job knob settings.
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6496039Z Start tracking orphan processes.
2020-07-17T10:10:18.6704567Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7101480Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout siems-batteriefinder@master to s
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7322904Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7323957Z Task         : Get sources
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7324536Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7326075Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7326668Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7327402Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-07-17T10:10:18.7327751Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8769903Z Syncing repository: siems-batteriefinder (Git)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8772760Z ##[command]git version
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8775640Z git version 2.27.0
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8776548Z ##[command]git lfs version
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8779578Z git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8780830Z ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8783374Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8784729Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://heinsohn-consulting@dev.azure.com/heinsohn-consulting/K-Siems%20Batteriefinder/_git/siems-batteriefinder
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8794645Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8798487Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://heinsohn-consulting@dev.azure.com/heinsohn-consulting/K-Siems%20Batteriefinder/_git/siems-batteriefinder.extraheader
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8802122Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8809715Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8812723Z remote: Azure Repos        
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8812913Z remote: 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8813129Z remote: Found 127 objects to send. (155 ms)        
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8813646Z Receiving objects:   0% (1/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8813899Z Receiving objects:   1% (2/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8814126Z Receiving objects:   2% (3/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8814352Z Receiving objects:   3% (4/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8814885Z Receiving objects:   4% (6/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8815135Z Receiving objects:   5% (7/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8815362Z Receiving objects:   6% (8/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8815587Z Receiving objects:   7% (9/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8815816Z Receiving objects:   8% (11/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8816062Z Receiving objects:   9% (12/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8816291Z Receiving objects:  10% (13/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8816520Z Receiving objects:  11% (14/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8816750Z Receiving objects:  12% (16/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8816993Z Receiving objects:  13% (17/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8817225Z Receiving objects:  14% (18/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8817454Z Receiving objects:  15% (20/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8817683Z Receiving objects:  16% (21/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8817939Z Receiving objects:  17% (22/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8818326Z Receiving objects:  18% (23/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8818559Z Receiving objects:  19% (25/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8818805Z Receiving objects:  20% (26/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8819048Z Receiving objects:  21% (27/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8819277Z Receiving objects:  22% (28/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8819505Z Receiving objects:  23% (30/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8819748Z Receiving objects:  24% (31/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8819977Z Receiving objects:  25% (32/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8820205Z Receiving objects:  26% (34/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8820435Z Receiving objects:  27% (35/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8820678Z Receiving objects:  28% (36/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8820908Z Receiving objects:  29% (37/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8821137Z Receiving objects:  30% (39/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8821366Z Receiving objects:  31% (40/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8821608Z Receiving objects:  32% (41/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8821975Z Receiving objects:  33% (42/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8822219Z Receiving objects:  34% (44/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8822449Z Receiving objects:  35% (45/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8822693Z Receiving objects:  36% (46/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8822934Z Receiving objects:  37% (47/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8823164Z Receiving objects:  38% (49/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8823394Z Receiving objects:  39% (50/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8823637Z Receiving objects:  40% (51/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8823866Z Receiving objects:  41% (53/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8824095Z Receiving objects:  42% (54/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8824326Z Receiving objects:  43% (55/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8824569Z Receiving objects:  44% (56/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8824799Z Receiving objects:  45% (58/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8825028Z Receiving objects:  46% (59/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8825257Z Receiving objects:  47% (60/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8825498Z Receiving objects:  48% (61/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8825728Z Receiving objects:  49% (63/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8825963Z Receiving objects:  50% (64/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8826193Z Receiving objects:  51% (65/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8826437Z Receiving objects:  52% (67/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8826667Z Receiving objects:  53% (68/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8826904Z Receiving objects:  54% (69/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8827134Z Receiving objects:  55% (70/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8827377Z Receiving objects:  56% (72/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8827607Z Receiving objects:  57% (73/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8827837Z Receiving objects:  58% (74/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8828066Z Receiving objects:  59% (75/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8828586Z Receiving objects:  60% (77/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8828806Z Receiving objects:  61% (78/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8829024Z Receiving objects:  62% (79/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8829252Z Receiving objects:  63% (81/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8829496Z Receiving objects:  64% (82/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8829725Z Receiving objects:  65% (83/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8829966Z Receiving objects:  66% (84/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8830197Z Receiving objects:  67% (86/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8830440Z Receiving objects:  68% (87/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8830670Z Receiving objects:  69% (88/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8830899Z Receiving objects:  70% (89/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8831304Z Receiving objects:  71% (91/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8831552Z Receiving objects:  72% (92/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8831781Z Receiving objects:  73% (93/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8832140Z Receiving objects:  74% (94/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8832363Z Receiving objects:  75% (96/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8832598Z Receiving objects:  76% (97/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8832820Z Receiving objects:  77% (98/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8833168Z Receiving objects:  78% (100/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8833402Z Receiving objects:  79% (101/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8833648Z Receiving objects:  80% (102/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8833880Z Receiving objects:  81% (103/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8834127Z Receiving objects:  82% (105/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8834383Z Receiving objects:  83% (106/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8834616Z Receiving objects:  84% (107/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8834848Z Receiving objects:  85% (108/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8835081Z Receiving objects:  86% (110/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8835339Z Receiving objects:  87% (111/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8835572Z Receiving objects:  88% (112/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8835804Z Receiving objects:  89% (114/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8836037Z Receiving objects:  90% (115/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8836284Z Receiving objects:  91% (116/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8836639Z Receiving objects:  92% (117/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8836865Z Receiving objects:  93% (119/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8837090Z Receiving objects:  94% (120/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8837328Z Receiving objects:  95% (121/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8837551Z Receiving objects:  96% (122/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8837775Z Receiving objects:  97% (124/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8837999Z Receiving objects:  98% (125/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8838310Z Receiving objects:  99% (126/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8838544Z Receiving objects: 100% (127/127)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8838820Z Receiving objects: 100% (127/127), 88.62 KiB | 22.15 MiB/s, done.
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8839101Z Resolving deltas:   0% (0/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8839323Z Resolving deltas:   9% (1/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8839535Z Resolving deltas:  36% (4/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8839746Z Resolving deltas:  45% (5/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8839970Z Resolving deltas:  72% (8/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8840297Z Resolving deltas:  81% (9/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8840515Z Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11)
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8840750Z Resolving deltas: 100% (11/11), done.
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8841480Z From https://dev.azure.com/heinsohn-consulting/K-Siems%20Batteriefinder/_git/siems-batteriefinder
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8842228Z  * [new branch]      deployment -> origin/deployment
2020-07-17T10:10:19.8842675Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9476665Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 4f47142e95f1a62852b7c04866a9a24912e742b9
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9479702Z Note: switching to '4f47142e95f1a62852b7c04866a9a24912e742b9'.
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9479919Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9480498Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9480880Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9481218Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9481438Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9481668Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9482229Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9482469Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9482811Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9482964Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9483137Z Or undo this operation with:
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9483291Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9483569Z   git switch -
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9483692Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9483959Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9484176Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9484605Z HEAD is now at 4f47142 Update azure-pipelines-2.yml for Azure Pipelines
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9537459Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout siems-batteriefinder@master to s
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9564013Z ##[section]Starting: Gradle package
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9573402Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9573725Z Task         : Gradle
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9574036Z Description  : Build using a Gradle wrapper script
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9574279Z Version      : 2.163.2
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9574534Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9574870Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle
2020-07-17T10:10:19.9575249Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:10:22.3660451Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2020-07-17T10:10:22.3661413Z [command]/home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew assemble
2020-07-17T10:10:24.5517746Z Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip
2020-07-17T10:10:29.5196790Z .............10%..............20%..............30%..............40%..............50%..............60%..............70%..............80%..............90%.............100%
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3530341Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3542386Z Welcome to Gradle 6.4.1!
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3582956Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3600688Z Here are the highlights of this release:
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3603402Z  - Support for building, testing and running Java Modules
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3605313Z  - Precompiled script plugins for Groovy DSL
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3607145Z  - Single dependency lock file per project
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3608779Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3610489Z For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/release-notes.html
2020-07-17T10:10:32.3611317Z 
2020-07-17T10:10:32.6433703Z Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
2020-07-17T10:11:23.7476279Z > Task :compileJava
2020-07-17T10:11:29.4470200Z > Task :processResources
2020-07-17T10:11:29.4549262Z > Task :classes
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1449551Z > Task :bootWar
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1450669Z > Task :war SKIPPED
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1451573Z > Task :assemble
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1452524Z 
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1453310Z Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1454825Z Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1455945Z See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1456658Z 
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1457276Z BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 9s
2020-07-17T10:11:33.1483382Z 3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
2020-07-17T10:11:33.5815216Z No test result files matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/**/TEST-*.xml were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
2020-07-17T10:11:33.5990379Z ##[section]Finishing: Gradle package
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6017757Z ##[section]Starting: Copy Files to artifact staging directory
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6026790Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6027096Z Task         : Copy files
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6027544Z Description  : Copy files from a source folder to a target folder using patterns matching file paths (not folder paths)
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6027886Z Version      : 2.164.2
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6028316Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6028735Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files
2020-07-17T10:11:33.6029113Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:33.7684988Z found 1 files
2020-07-17T10:11:33.7695601Z Copying /home/vsts/work/1/s/build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /home/vsts/work/1/a/build/libs/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8452791Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files to artifact staging directory
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8524865Z ##[section]Starting: PublishPipelineArtifact
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8532658Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8532978Z Task         : Publish pipeline artifact
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8533477Z Description  : Publish a local directory or file as a named artifact for the current pipeline
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8533757Z Version      : 0.140.1
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8533980Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8534415Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
2020-07-17T10:11:33.8534762Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:34.2023350Z Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/vsts/work/1/a for build #66
2020-07-17T10:11:35.1649863Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session e7359fd5-57a4-4e8c-ab59-eb2f74cb3ee3
2020-07-17T10:11:35.1861494Z DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session e7359fd5-57a4-4e8c-ab59-eb2f74cb3ee3
2020-07-17T10:11:36.4376847Z 1 files processed.
2020-07-17T10:11:36.4389760Z Processed 1 files from /home/vsts/work/1/a successfully.
2020-07-17T10:11:40.1955274Z Uploading 1 files from directory /home/vsts/work/1/a.
2020-07-17T10:11:40.1970517Z Uploaded 0 out of 80,301,669 bytes.
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2943581Z Uploaded 14,492,335 out of 80,301,874 bytes
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2944323Z Content upload is done!
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2953879Z 
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2954455Z Content upload statistics:
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2954782Z Total Content: 160.6 MB
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2955017Z Physical Content Uploaded: 12.3 MB
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2955269Z Logical Content Uploaded: 14.5 MB
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2955500Z Compression Saved: 2.2 MB
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2955741Z Deduplication Saved: 146.1 MB
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2955978Z Number of Chunks Uploaded: 161
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2956495Z Total Number of Chunks: 3,582
2020-07-17T10:11:43.2956684Z 
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6023302Z Associated artifact 21 with build 66
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6039564Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session e7359fd5-57a4-4e8c-ab59-eb2f74cb3ee3
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6043132Z Uploading pipeline artifact finished.
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6128789Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishPipelineArtifact
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6155964Z ##[section]Starting: Checkout siems-batteriefinder@master to s
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6162842Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6163246Z Task         : Get sources
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6163519Z Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6163795Z Version      : 1.0.0
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6163986Z Author       : Microsoft
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6164284Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
2020-07-17T10:11:44.6164609Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9359727Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: siems-batteriefinder (Git)
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9404234Z ##[section]Finishing: Checkout siems-batteriefinder@master to s
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9460763Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9494241Z Cleaning up task key
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9495545Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9810386Z Terminate orphan process: pid (2595) (java)
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9817843Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2020-07-17T10:11:44.9858525Z ##[section]Finishing: Gradle Package and Publish Artifacts
```

The deployment logs:

```
2020-07-17T10:11:57.7935477Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Linux Web App
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9733819Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9735194Z Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9735587Z Agent machine name: 'fv-az695'
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9735859Z Current agent version: '2.172.1'
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9779027Z ##[group]Operating System
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9779308Z Ubuntu
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9779474Z 18.04.4
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9779648Z LTS
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9779822Z ##[endgroup]
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9780018Z ##[group]Virtual Environment
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9780265Z Environment: ubuntu-18.04
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9780478Z Version: 20200709.0
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9780839Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu18/20200709.0/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9781171Z ##[endgroup]
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9782281Z Current image version: '20200709.0'
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9787187Z Agent running as: 'vsts'
2020-07-17T10:11:57.9838509Z Prepare build directory.
2020-07-17T10:11:58.0174741Z Set build variables.
2020-07-17T10:11:58.0212645Z Download all required tasks.
2020-07-17T10:11:58.0337019Z Downloading task: DownloadPipelineArtifact (1.2.5)
2020-07-17T10:11:58.9626410Z Downloading task: AzureWebApp (1.168.2)
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4284776Z Checking job knob settings.
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4294032Z    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /opt/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4295212Z    Knob: AgentPerflog = /home/vsts/perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4295845Z Finished checking job knob settings.
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4606911Z Start tracking orphan processes.
2020-07-17T10:12:00.4807714Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5180968Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifact
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5415487Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5416379Z Task         : Download pipeline artifact
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5416997Z Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5417419Z Version      : 1.2.5
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5417956Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5418760Z Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2020-07-17T10:12:00.5419115Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:12:01.4316431Z Download from the specified build: #66
2020-07-17T10:12:01.4316874Z Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4277421Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session bb0bd98b-4554-411b-bfbf-6a3799bb2898
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4334354Z Downloading 1 pipeline artifacts...
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4335259Z DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session bb0bd98b-4554-411b-bfbf-6a3799bb2898
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4335837Z Start downloading artifact - drop
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4336078Z Minimatch patterns: [**]
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4336329Z Filtered 1 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.
2020-07-17T10:12:02.4336620Z Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 80.3 MB (0%).
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9777424Z Downloaded 80.3 MB out of 80.3 MB (100%).
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9806209Z 
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9807578Z Download statistics:
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9808364Z Total Content: 80.3 MB
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9809215Z Physical Content Downloaded: 75.3 MB
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9810021Z Compression Saved: 5.0 MB
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9810757Z Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9811556Z Chunks Downloaded: 1,023
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9812305Z Nodes Downloaded: 2
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9812823Z 
2020-07-17T10:12:06.9924851Z Download completed.
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6158458Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session bb0bd98b-4554-411b-bfbf-6a3799bb2898
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6167007Z Downloading artifact finished.
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6433177Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifact
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6468154Z ##[section]Starting: Azure Web App Deploy: batteriefinder
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6481531Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6481889Z Task         : Azure Web App
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6482185Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Web App for Linux or Windows
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6482467Z Version      : 1.168.2
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6482711Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6483033Z Help         : https://aka.ms/azurewebapptroubleshooting
2020-07-17T10:12:07.6483380Z ==============================================================================
2020-07-17T10:12:08.3604159Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'batteriefinder'
2020-07-17T10:12:09.3398253Z Package deployment using WAR Deploy initiated.
2020-07-17T10:12:48.4383347Z Deploy logs can be viewed at https://batteriefinder.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/cb3b346f70a44f00a3042ff85af7d01a/log
2020-07-17T10:12:48.4384148Z Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
2020-07-17T10:12:50.5218168Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://batteriefinder.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/661594980770124
2020-07-17T10:12:50.8645528Z App Service Application URL: http://batteriefinder.azurewebsites.net
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5046794Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure Web App Deploy: batteriefinder
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5106083Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5138986Z Cleaning up task key
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5140414Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5439196Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2020-07-17T10:12:51.5480932Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Linux Web App
```

The URL of the App Service: http://batteriefinder.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please login azure portal->App Service->configuration->Default documents

Default documents list is ordered by precedence. Items towards the top of the list will have higher precedence than items at the bottom of the list.

Please ensure that your default page is listed in here and is above hostingstart.html
[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately I do not have this point.
I only have application settings, general settings and path mappings. Do you have any idea why this is so?

Comment: Please login Azure portal->App Services->Deployment Center configure it.
In addition, please also login https://batteriefinder.scm.azurewebsites.net/error/unauthorized and check it.